# Is any way to automatically add paths to used units in dpr and contained units in dpk files?

Tags: delphi

I have some projects and packages with a list of units without paths. To not depend of project's and IDE's search paths and directly point to desired files I want to explicitly specify path's, like Delphi makes when I use "Add to project" feature.

Is any way to make it automatically, not by hand for each unit?

Comment: You either use search path, or you specify the path explicitly.

Comment: I want to switch from using search paths to using explicitly specified paths.

Comment: So remove the search paths from the project options and modify the .dpr and .dpk files to include all the required units.

Comment: Question just about that! How to add that units's paths automatically!

Comment: If you add the units using **Project | Add to project** then the IDE will do it all for you

Comment: No. These files are already in uses, and "Add to project" do nothing for them. I can remove it first, but it's still not so easy if most of paths are different and in those folders contain many other units.

Comment: Removing, and re-adding is the only way to get the IDE to do it for you. The alternative would be to write some code to modify the .dpr file for you

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144558/discussion-between-nashev-and-david-heffernan).